# Custom Circular progressbar with thumb Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

I'm trying to get a data from an API, then push it and display it in a Progressbar, it displays many informations, for the time it's working but I want to add a thumb and a moving text that points on the progress end, also the thumb at the end.
First of all, here's my progress bar image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIeE7.jpg

I tried seekbar but didn't work for me as I have many textViews inside the layout, 
Here's my code for the xml progressbar

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="205dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="105dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"

        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="65"

        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

Also drawable_circular_progress.xml

```
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="6dp"
            android:useLevel="true">

            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="#DB0021"
                android:startColor="#F9590D"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false" />
        </shape>

    </rotate>
```

circle_shape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"

        android:thickness="3dp"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="#979797" />

    </shape>
```

So I want to make a dynamic text and an icon who will progress with the bar.
will this be possible?
Thanks for you help